# How to take average of time column and show the output as time

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to take average of time column and show the output as a time column

I've written a SQL query which is giving me wrong output.

```
SELECT
  SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date,
  cast(avg(SOD_End_Time) as time),
  avg(SOD_End_Time)
FROM aap_auto
group by SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date;
```

Here is the input

```
SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date, SOD_End_Time
2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:45:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:50:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 06:00:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:40:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:48:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:55:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:35:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:38:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:42:00

2019-08-09 00:00:00, 05:36:00
```

Here is the output

```
SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date, cast(avg(SOD_End_Time) as time), avg(SOD_End_Time)

2019-08-09 00:00:00, null, 54890.0000
```

Here 'cast' is giving null as output.
For some cases, this query is giving correct output

```
SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date, cast(avg(SOD_End_Time) as time), avg(SOD_End_Time)

2019-08-10 00:00:00, 05:46:20, 54620.0000
```

Comment: Can you post the results off  `SHOW CREATE TABLE aap_auto`  to make sure we can reproduce the problem better..

Answer (score 1):

If have tried it with SOD_End_Time as varchar and as time and i never get your time

```
CREATE TABLE aap_auto
(`SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date` datetime, `SOD_End_Time` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO aap_auto
(`SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date`, `SOD_End_Time`)
VALUES
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:45:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:50:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '06:00:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:40:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:48:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:55:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:35:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:38:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:42:00'),
('2019-08-09 00:00:00', '05:36:00')
;
```

You getht with

```
SELECT
  SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(avg(TIME_TO_SEC(SOD_End_Time))),'%H:%i%s' ),
  avg(SOD_End_Time)
FROM aap_auto
group by SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date;
```

following result

```
SOD_EOD_Job_Ran_Date    SEC_TO_TIME(avg(TIME_TO_SEC(SOD_End_Time)))     avg(SOD_End_Time)
 2019-08-09T00:00:00Z   05:44:54                                        5.1
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is working for me. But i'm getting sec_to_time value as '05:44:54.0000'. Can you suggest any change in query so that i can remove extra zeros from final output